# GitLab Runner Windows: Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The directory name is invalid

Tags: windows, git, amazon-ec2, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I created an AWS EC2 instance using Windows 2022 server AMI and installed a GitLab runner on it. Whenever I run a job on it, it works fine but for some reason, shows the following error: `Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The directory name is invalid`

Here is a snippet of the job logs:

```yaml
Running with gitlab-runner 15.11.0 (436955cb)
  on windows-gitlab-runner xxxxxxxx, system ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Resolving secrets
00:00
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell (powershell) executor...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on EC2AMAZ-XXXXXXX...
Getting source from Git repository
00:11
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/Windows/System32/builds/xxxxxxxx/0/User.Name/gitlab-repo-name/.git/
Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The directory name is invalid
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at GitCredentialManager.GitProcess.get_Version()
   at GitCredentialManager.GitProcessConfiguration.GetCanonicalizeTypeArg(GitConfigurationType type)
   at GitCredentialManager.GitProcessConfiguration.TryGet(GitConfigurationLevel level, GitConfigurationType type, String name, String& value)
   at GitCredentialManager.GitConfigurationExtensions.TryGet(IGitConfiguration config, String name, Boolean isPath, String& value)
   at GitCredentialManager.Settings.<GetSettingValues>d__5.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at GitCredentialManager.Settings.TryGetSetting(String envarName, String section, String property, String& value)
   at GitCredentialManager.Settings.GetTrace2Settings()
   at GitCredentialManager.CommandContext..ctor(String[] argv)
   at GitCredentialManager.Program.Main(String[] args)
Checking out b0c4cb08 as detached HEAD (ref is main)...
git-lfs/3.3.0 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.19.3; git 77deabdf)
.
.
.
```

What is the root cause of this and how to fix this?